# Complemento en Firefox JavaScript - Enlazar aplicación nativa con promises

Tags: javascript, promesas, firefox, firefox-webextensions

Estoy desarrollando un complemento para Firefox +57 mediante WebExtension.
Este complemento comunica con una aplicación nativa .exe , con la cual tengo abierto un único puerto con el cual realizo la comunicación complemento-appNativa.
Simplificando, el complemento realiza una autentición basica la cual usa listener y promesas.
La duda es: como comunico los listener de mi App nativa con los listeners de autenticación basica mediante promesas. Lo veremos mejor con código:

```
var port;
try {
   port = browser.runtime.connectNative("miAPP");
   port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
} catch(err) {
   Console.log(err.message);
}  

    //Native message listener
function onNativeMessage(message) {
 .
 .more code
 .
  else if (message.response == "autenticacionBasica") {
    processBasicAuth(message.data);
  }

}
function basicAuthListener(requestDetails) {
//*
//AQUI VA CODIGO PARA PREPARAR MI PETICION A LA APP NATIVA
//CUYA RESPUESTA RECOGERÉ EN EL METODO DEL LISTENER processBasicAuth
*/
var request;

//preparar request mediante requestDetails y enviar

port.postMessage(request);

    if (pendingRequests.indexOf(requestDetails.requestId) != -1) {

        //retun PROMESA CON EL CANCEL

    } else {
        pendingRequests.push(requestDetails.requestId);             
        // return PROMESA CON LAS CREDENCIALES                                  
    }
}

function processBasicAuth(message) {

    if(message.action == "ok" ) {
        //resolver PROMESA con:         
        /*{
            authCredentials: {
                username: message.username, 
                password: message.password
            }
        }*/ 
    }else{
        // Resolver una PROMESA con "{cancel : true}"           
    }
}   

function completed(requestDetails) {
    var index = pendingRequests.indexOf(requestDetails.requestId);
    if (index > -1) {
    pendingRequests.splice(index, 1); 
    }   
}

browser.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(basicAuthListener, filter, extraInfoSpec);
browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener( completed, filter);
browser.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener( completed,filter);

//Fin codigo
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda y a partir de hoy comienzo mi aventura activamente en esta comunidad.